# Fetching values from cursor in android

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

i am fetching a query from sqlite database like that :

```
String query = "select distinct(" +MessageCountConstant.To_USER + "), sum(" +MessageCountConstant.SEND_MESSAGE_COUNT + ") , "
            + "sum(" +MessageCountConstant.RECIEVE_MESSAGE_COUNT + ") from " +TABLE_NAME + " where " + MessageCountConstant.DATE  + "= " +date
             + " AND "+ MessageCountConstant.DATE  + " >= "+previousDate + " AND "+ MessageCountConstant.JID + " = '"+ Uname + "'"
                        ;


    SQLiteDatabase db = mOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
```

Now can anyone tell me how can i fetch value from cursor .Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use it in that way

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()){

 do{
      String data = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("data");

      // do what ever you want here

   }while(cursor.moveToNext());

}

cursor.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you can get your values from the cursor by doing the following:

```
while( cursor.moveToNext() ) {
    String value1 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("column1"));
    String value2 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("column2"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do fetch data like that :

```
for(cursor.move(0);cursor.moveToNext();cursor.isAfterLast()){
   String first = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("string_row"));
   int second cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumgnIndex("int_row"));
}
```

and don't forget to close your cursor after fetching data : `cursor.close();`